# Does install4j have a built-in Action/API for dealing with Windows short (8.3) file-names?

Tags: install4j

I am using install4j to build an installer for an application that requires I do a search and replace in a properties file with the Windows Short filename/path for the installation directory.  I already have a 'Modify Text Files' action that does the following:

```
Search Value:  INCHOME=C:\dev\inc\1.0
Replace Value: INCHOME=${installer:sys.installationDir}
```

In my case this will generally be C:\Program Files\InControl.

I need to be able to change the value of ${installer:sys.installationDir} and consequently "C:\Program Files\InControl" to something like "C:\PROGRA~1\InControl" although this of course could vary based on Windows rules for this.

I have read through the solution made available at:

http://dolf.trieschnigg.nl/eightpointthree/eightpointthree.html

Which seems to be a generally accepted/used solutoin.  Does install4j have something built-in to handle this or do I need to include something like this as custom code?

If I have to include it as custom code, how do I include the native windows libraries?

I couldn't find anything in com.install4j.api.windows.WinFileSystem or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the API, but you can use

```
com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.FolderInfo.getShortPathName(String longPathName)
```

Comment: One question. How do I use this in the context of a "Run Script" action?  I tried importing that path and using the getShortPathName method but the Run Script action fails to pass compilation.

Comment: @Frank The "FolderInfo" class was missing, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ha, thanks.  I found it while I was waiting but using jad.  Worked great.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it working.  A slight variation on your path above, I had to use jad to decompile the classes to find it, but the following (with the addition of the FileInfo Class) worked:

```
import com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.*;

String incHome = (String)context.getVariable("sys.installationDir");
String incHomeShort = FolderInfo.getShortPathName(incHome);

context.setVariable("incHomeShort", incHomeShort);
```

Thanks!